# Trouble with setting up/creating Stripe Connect Accounts

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I have a function that attempts to do a `POST API` request to Stripe's servers:

```
func createAccount() {
        
        let individualParams = STPConnectAccountIndividualParams()
        individualParams.firstName = "John"
        individualParams.lastName = "Doe"
        individualParams.email = "john.doe@example.com"
        individualParams.address!.line1 = "123 Main St"
        individualParams.address!.city = "San Francisco"
        individualParams.address!.state = "CA"
        individualParams.address!.postalCode = "94111"
        individualParams.address!.country = "US"
        individualParams.phone = "+14155552671"
        //individualParams.dateOfBirth = STPDateOfBirth(
        //    day: 1,
        //    month: 1,
        //    year: 1990
        //)
        
        let accountParams = STPConnectAccountParams(individual: individualParams)
        accountParams.company!.name = "My Company"
        accountParams.company!.address.line1 = "123 Main St"
        accountParams.company!.address.city = "San Francisco"
        accountParams.company!.address.state = "CA"
        accountParams.company!.address.postalCode = "94111"
        accountParams.company!.address.country = "US"
        //accountParams.tosShownAndAccepted = true
        
        let stripeClient = STPAPIClient()
        stripeClient.publishableKey = "pk_test_[NOT-FOR-YOU]"
        stripeClient.stripeAccount = "acct_[NOT-FOR-YOU]"
        stripeClient.configuration = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared

        stripeClient.createAccount(with: accountParams) { (account, error) in
            if let account = account {
                print("Account created with ID: \(account.stripeID)")
                sellerID = account.stripeID
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Error creating account: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Did I even make this function correctly? I am very new to Stripe and have no clue what I am doing. If needed, I can also supply my server's code.
Thanks again, Anish

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a connected account directly from a mobile app.

First there's no `createAccount()` method in [STPAPIClient](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/stripe/documentation/stripe/stpapiclient). Second creating a connected account requires a secret key, and you need to do it from you backend where the secret key is stored.

Comment: How would I create an account? I would also like to store the user's ID.

Comment: You can refer to the API reference here (https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account). And I'd also suggest you to read through this doc (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/explore-connect-guide) before deciding what type of account is suitable to your business.

Comment: Oh yeah, I had to redirect the user to an external website to create an account. I completely forgot, thank you.